# Create variable EC2 instances via nested stack ; not autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I want to **create variable number of EC2 instances** (inputted by user) via CloudFormation.I am thinking of using **stacks or nested stacks**. I do not want to repeat AWS::EC2:: Instance in my template.

I want something like a ***nested template, which will do the EC2 creation itself, and call it N times from master stack, feeding it each time with the same parameters***.

Is there any template for the same?

Also is there any better way?

Comment: AFAIK there is no straightforward way to achieve this. Check CloudFormation macros: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html. It transforms your template. It's a little complicated, but gets the job done.

Comment: I'd also check https://aws.amazon.com/de/cdk/.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004Do have any examples where macro is used to launch instances?